# Have mvn dependency:list print out all artifacts in a group except for those in a sub-group?

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I'm trying to list all artifacts in `com.example`, except those in `com.example.foo.bar`.

For `mvn dependency:tree`, I can do this:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dexcludes=*bar* -Dincludes=com.example.*
```

However, when I try:

```
mvn dependency:list -DexcludeGroupIds=com.example.foo.bar -DincludeGroupIds=com.example
```

Maven still lists everything in `bar`.

**Question**: How can I mirror the results from `dependency:tree` using `list`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference between include/excludes of `tree` vs `list` is that the former expects a **pattern** while the latter exact matchings.

For instance, the [`includes`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html#includes) option of the `tree` goal can have a value:

> where each pattern segment is optional and supports full and partial * wildcards.

On the other hand, the [`includeGroupIds`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/list-mojo.html#includeGroupIds) option of the `list` goal is a simple:

> Comma separated list of GroupIds to include.

---

Given the following dependencies example:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- other dependencies with different groupIds than the prefix org.apache -->
    ...
</dependencies>
```

If we want to include only `commons` but exclude `logging` for both goals we should run:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=org.apache.* -Dexcludes=*logging*
```

Note the wildcards applied to both patterns. We need both options, since the first doesn't exclude the second.

For the `list` goal in this case only inclusion would be enough, since we list only what we actually want:

```
mvn dependency:list -DincludeGroupIds=org.apache.commons
```

Comment: So, if I don't know the sub-groups of `com.example` that are used (and only know I don't want `com.example.foo` and its sub-groups), I can't use `list`, correct?

Comment: @Christian indeed, you need to know them, otherwise they can't be matched by `list`. `tree` is much more flexible, relying on patterns instead.